# screen and tmux sessions 'dissappearing' on ssh logout

Tags: ubuntu, screen, tmux

I have tried this with both screen and tmux; but will provide the walkthrough with tmux

I am using an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-1014-aws aarch64) remote server.

I will login to the session; start a new tmux session

`tmux new -s session1 -d`

`tmux attach -t session1`

run bash script

`bash stuff.sh`

wait.
.

I return after a few hours, log back in and run

`tmux ls`

and get

`no server running on /tmp/tmux-2001257/default`

The bash script is perpetual

Comment: Was your problem solved after ssh logout?

Comment: Thank you @MdAbrarJahin the issue was not resolved

I was told that this might be a 'feature' of the new AWS EC2 instances